# Reloading keyboard shortcut definitions in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, key-bindings, pharo

I've been playing around with keyboard shortcuts in Pharo  7.0. I wanted to modify the binding for `#jumpToNextKeywordOfIt` in the Smalltalk editor and so I got the following change in the definition of `buildShortcutsOn` method:

```
(aBuilder shortcut: #jumpToNextKeywordOfIt)
    category: RubSmalltalkEditor name
    default: $y meta shift
    do: [ :target | target editor jumpToNextKeywordOfIt: true ]
    description: 'Jump to next keyword'.
```

My first thought was that just saving this definition should immediately take effect, but it was not the case. Then I thought, perhaps since this is part of a method definition, then calling this method on the editor class would do the trick. Now, the method takes an argument `aBuilder` and I don't really know what that is. So two questions arise:

1. Is this the proper way to apply keybinding changes to a running editor?
2. What is `aBuilder` in this context and how does one get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me give you some hints on how to find the solution (as this might be more valuable than giving the solution at once)

The problem is what's `aBuilder` right? Well, from the expression

```
(aBuilder shortcut: #jumpToNextKeywordOfIt)
```

we deduce that `aBuilder` is someone that responds to `#shortcut:`. Cmd+m and you will get 9 implementors of `#shortcut:`. One of them, `KMBuilder` has an interesting name. Moreover, its implementation of `shortcut:` is

```
shortcut: aKeymapName
  ^KMKeymapBuilder 
    for: aKeymapName
    platform: platform
```

meaning that it will answer with an instance of `KMKeymapBuilder`. Browse this class and verify that it understands the next message from your expression:

```
category: RubSmalltalkEditor name
default: $y meta shift
do: [ :target | target editor jumpToNextKeywordOfIt: true ]
description: 'Jump to next keyword'.
```

It does! So this must be it! To check this, we still need an instance of `KMBuilder`. Browse the class, go to the class side and find the unary message `#keymap`.

This means that we can obtain `aBuilder` by evaluating

```
KMBuilder keymap
```

I love unary messages. Specially when they are on the class side!

Now go to the implementor of the method you already tweaked `#buildShortcutsOn:`. It is implemented in the class side and we can now evaluate:

```
RubTextEditor buildShortcutsOn: KMBuilder keymap
```

To make sure that it works, go now to the desired handler `#jumpToNextKeywordOfIt:` and insert a `halt` in it. This is in the same class, instance side.

Now lets press Cmd+Shift+y and see if we get the halt... Bingo! I mean, Halt!

Comment: Thank you very much Leandro! This was indeed enlightening and I'm grateful to you for giving more than just an answer to my question.. I was also able to see that some of my problems with Pharo keybindings are due to Xfce's meddling - I'll have to look into it. Specifically, the `$y meta shift` binding, which on my system translates to `Ctrl+Shift+Y`, failed to produce the desired effect.